How to represent a max integer value in Gleam
In languages like python we have functions like math.inf or float("inf") to represent an infinite value that can still be used as a number.
Does Gleam contain a function or operation that performs a similar task?
I looked through the gleam/int and the rest of stdlib and couldn't find anything that matched what I needed to do.

I don't know the first thing about Gleam, but I found this on tour.gleam.run: "When running on the Erlang virtual machine ints have no maximum and minimum size. When running on JavaScript runtimes ints are represented using JavaScript's 64 bit floating point numbers"

Thanks, I guess I will limit my program to the 64 bit float that JS uses.
